# Matching end-of-line or end-of-file using nom

Tags: parsing, rust

I'm trying to parse a string using nom that will either be terminated by a newline or will reach end-of-input once consumed. I have the following code which seems like it should compile:

```
named!(am_implied <AddressingMode>,
    do_parse!(
        opt!(space) >>
        alt!(
            line_ending |
            eof!()
        ) >>
        (AddressingMode::Implied)
    )
);
```

This fails with the following message:

```
error[E0282]: unable to infer enough type information about `E`
   --> src/lib.rs:181:1
    |
181 | named!(am_implied <AddressingMode>,
    | ^ cannot infer type for `E`
    |
    = note: type annotations or generic parameter binding required
```

I'm led to believe that the above code should compile since following code compiles:

```
named!(am_implied <AddressingMode>,
    do_parse!(
        opt!(space) >>
        line_ending >>
        eof!() >>
        (AddressingMode::Implied)
    )
);
```

I'm confused as to why this works when the `line_ending` and `eof!` parsers aren't used within an `alt!` parser, but fails when they are. I'd like to know the correct solution to matching on `line_ending` or `eof!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it's [this issue in nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom/issues/308), and this [WIP PR](https://github.com/Geal/nom/pull/413).  Essentially there aren't enough type hints provided by some of the nom macros, so the inference fails.

The suggested workaround is to split some of the sub-parsers into separate parsers to help the type inference, but that didn't work for me when I tried it in this case.